SPL-Token-2022 Fee Epoch length
Good evening,
I am just wondering how long an Epochs for the Transfer Fees are.
I Just playing around with that in a localtestnet and wondering when the epoches Changed.
As i setted new Fees, Set the test-validator and expected it Just uses the Default Epoch length (specified to 500 Blocks on the Test Validator.
Greetings

The epochs are Solana epochs, so every 432,000 slots.
You can look around at some of the terminology starting at https://solana.com/docs/terminology#epoch and https://solana.com/docs/terminology#slot
